# executar um script automaticamente

Tags: php, javascript

como posso executar este script abaixo, no momento que o input label for preenchido?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var serie = $('#serie_maquina').val();
    var grupo = $('#grupo_maquina').val();
    console.log(serie);
    console.log(grupo);
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url: 'info_maquina_consulta.php',
        data: {
            'serie':serie,
            'grupo':grupo
        },
        erro: function(){
            alert('erro');
        },
        success: function(data){
            $("#maquina_carrega").html(data);
        }

    });
});
```

EDIT1
segue html como pedido:

```
<form>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="input-group input-group-md">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1">Numero Serie</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="serie_maquina" id="serie_maquina">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="input-group input-group-md">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1">Modelo</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="grupo_maquina" id="grupo_maquina">
        </div>
    </div>
    <button id="btn_consulta" type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-success">Pesquisar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: O que seria input label?

Comment: Adicione o HTML tornará o problema mais fácil de ser entendido

Comment: editei o post com o html!

Comment: Supondo que eu tenha um botão que receba de uma consulta  um value="". como passo esse valor para uma variavel php em um modal?

Comment: No caso, vc não quer mais que seja executado ao abrir a página?

Comment: Peço que elabore novamente a pergunta porque seu post original coloca uma questão e depois aqui nos comentários você questiona outra coisa.  Com isso, não está clara a questão para a qual você realmente procura resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar o evento `focusout` para executar assim que o input for preenchido e perder o foco

```
$('#inputId').on('focusout', function() {
    //código a ser executado
});
```

ou usar o `keyup` que executa sempre quando uma tecla é pressionada e retorna a sua posição original, fazendo com que o script rode ao mesmo tempo que é digitado algo no input

```
$('#inputId').on('keyup', function() {
    //código a ser executado
});
```